# How to get number of people user is following

Tags: .net, vb.net, twitter, twitterizer

I already have the following code which successfully retrieves the number of people following a user:

```
Dim followersResponse As TwitterResponse(Of UserIdCollection) = TwitterFriendship.FollowersIds(tokens)
If followersResponse.Result <> RequestResult.Success Then
Else
labelNumFollowers.Text = followersResponse.ResponseObject.Count
End If
```

But what I can't figure out is how to retrieve the total number of people ***being followed*** by the user.

***(I'd also like to know if there's a way of identifying the total number of tweets a user has published.)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for amount of followers is a bit weird, it's: NumberOfFriends.
To get the amount of tweets a user has sent, use NumberOfStatuses

```
Dim showUserResponse As TwitterResponse(Of TwitterUser) = TwitterUser.Show(tokens, labelUsername.Text)
labelNumFollowing.Text = showUserResponse.ResponseObject.NumberOfFriends
labelNumTweets.Text = showUserResponse.ResponseObject.NumberOfStatuses
```

I hope the VB syntax is correct, since I'm a C# programmer